# numpy image replace areas with equal values

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

So I have a gray (2D) image of type np.array with a lot of zeros and objects inside of it. Each object is defined by its pixels having the same value, e.g. 1.23e15.

I now want to label the image, i.e. I want to rescale all pixels of a certain value (eg 200 pixels of the above value 1.23e15) to one integer number. 
Apart from the background which is zero, I want each region to be set to one of the values in range(1,nbr_of_regions_in_img+1).

How can I do this time efficiently (I have hundreds of thousands of images) without the obvious looping solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scipy has an [extensive library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.7.1/reference/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage) for image manipulation and analysis. The function, you are looking for is probably [`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.7.1/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html#segmentation-and-labeling)

```
import scipy.ndimage
import numpy as np

pix = np.array([[0,0,1,1,0,0],
                [0,0,1,1,1,0],
                [1,1,0,0,1,0],
                [0,1,0,0,0,0]])
mask_obj, n_obj = scipy.ndimage.label(pix)
```

The output gives you both, a labelled mask with a different number for each identified object and the number of identified objects.

```
>>>print(n_obj)
>>>2
>>>print(mask_obj)
>>>[[0 0 1 1 0 0]
    [0 0 1 1 1 0]
    [2 2 0 0 1 0]
    [0 2 0 0 0 0]]
```

You can also define, what should count as a neighbouring cell with the `structure` parameter:

```
s = np.asarray([[1,1,1],
                [1,1,1],
                [1,1,1]])

mask_obj, n_obj = scipy.ndimage.label(pix, structure = s)
>>>print(n_obj)
>>>1
>>>print(mask_obj) 
>>>[[0 0 1 1 0 0]
    [0 0 1 1 1 0]
    [1 1 0 0 1 0]
    [0 1 0 0 0 0]]
```

Difficulties will arise, if different objects touch each other, i.e. they are not separated by a zero value.